# How to access fields from the inner join

Tags: apex, soql

I need to access the fields from the nested Select statement.  Here is the code

```
Select Name, id, (SELECT id FROM Account.Contacts)
       from Account where id = '0011a000004eVlYAAU'
```

How do I access the "id" from "Account.Contacts".  I found an answer but I am not able to make it work.

```
For(string b : [Select Name, id, (SELECT id FROM Account.Contacts)
       from Account where id = '0011a000004eVlYAAU'])
        {

            system.debug(b.Account.Contacts);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Inner query always return list of child records. So for each record retrieved by the outer query, a list of child records are available through the inner query.

To access the records returned by the inner query, you can assign them to a list and iterate over it.

```
for(Account acc : [Select Name, id, (SELECT id FROM Account.Contacts) from Account]){
    List<Contact> lstContact = acc.Contacts;
    for(Contact con : lstContact){
        System.debug(con.Id);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Vigneshwaran that was an incredibly fast response I will try that and let you know if it worked!